# NDK memory saturation

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I had to use NDK in my java code to call some audio processing functions, but i have never tried JNI or C/C++ coding. I tried to start from the scratch but i really have no time. so i found this library [here](http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/res/free-small-fft-in-multiple-languages/fft.c) and tried to use it. I always get a `fatal signal 11 (sigsegv)` error. I really don't know where to start. here's what i have done so far:

in the Android Activity:

```
public native int transform(double[] real,double[]imag, int n);
public native int convolve(double[]xreal,double[]ximag,double[]yreal,double[]yimag,double[]outreal,double[]outim, int n);
```

and they are called in the same file like this :

```
transform(raw1, imag1,raw1.length);//result back into each vector
transform(raw2, imag2,raw2.length);
convolve(raw1,imag1,raw2,imag2,outre,outim,raw1.length);
```

in the C file:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_ffttest_FFTActivity_transform
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jdoubleArray real, jdoubleArray imag, jint n)
    {
       if (n == 0)
           return 1;
       else if ((n & (n - 1)) == 0)  // Is power of 2
           return transform_radix2(real, imag, n);
       else  // More complicated algorithm for arbitrary sizes
           return transform_bluestein(real, imag, n);
    }
```

and made some changes to the convolve function:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_ffttest_FFTActivity_convolve
 (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jdoubleArray xreal, jdoubleArray ximag, jdoubleArray yreal,                       jdoubleArray yimag, jdoubleArray outreal, jdoubleArray outimag, jint n)
   {
    //size = n * sizeof(double);
     n = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, xreal);

jdouble *a=(*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env,xreal,0);
jdouble *b=(*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env,ximag,0);
jdouble *c=(*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env,yreal,0);
jdouble *d=(*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env,yimag,0);
jdouble *e=(*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env,outreal,0);
jdouble *f=(*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env,outimag,0);
...
```

Is there some changes i need to know from C to JNI?

Comment: The place to start is to figure out which line of code it's on when it crashes.  The logcat output should have a backtrace, and show a fault address.

Comment: yes i tried it stops when calling the first non jni function  transform_radix2(real, imag, n)

Comment: You should paste the fault address and stack backtrace from logcat in the question.

Comment: the only message i get is 'fatal signal 11 (sigsegv)' when the debugger steps into transform_radix(real,imag,n) call.